# Tcl regexp : Why '+' does not match as many as possible?

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using TCL8.4. In the following expression, I tried to fetch the numerical value using ([0-9]+). But it does not matches as many as possible though man page shows '+' is meant for matching as many as possible ( ref : http://wiki.tcl.tk/396)
Also, please share/suggest any better way of doing what I want to do.

```
%set a {
NOTPLD STATS:
              Bps:                    0; pps:                    0; Bytes:                    0; Packets:                    4535

TPLD STATS:
          Bps:                    0; pps:                    0; Bytes:                    0; Packets:                    4535

}
%
% regexp {NOTPLD STATS:(.*?)Packets:[\s]+([0-9]+)} $a t1 t2 c 
1
% set c
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [*Interaction Between Quantifiers with Different Greediness*](http://wiki.tcl.tk/396):

> All quantifiers in a branch get switched to the same greediness, so adding a non-greedy quantifier makes the other quantifiers in the branch implicitly non-greedy as well.

Thus, your `([0-9]+)` is interpreted as `([0-9]+?)`, and it matches one or more digits, but as few as possible to return a valid match. **All lazy subpatterns at the end of patterns only match zero (`*?`) or one (`+?`) symbols.**

A simple solution is just to add a trailing character, here, it is a newline (or whitespace):

```
regexp {NOTPLD STATS:(.*?)Packets:[\s]+([0-9]+)\s} $a t1 t2 c
                                                ^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6Vt3HM)

If the value can be at the end of the string, use an alternation `(?:\s|$)`.

Comment: This is an area where the Tcl RE engine requires post-graduate level study to understand. I can see a few aspects of it, but usually have to experiment with REs to get them right. The `\y` word-boundary anchor can help.

Comment: Or a lookahead solution: [`regexp {NOTPLD STATS:((?:(?!Packets:).)*)Packets:[\s]+([0-9]+)} $a t1 t2 c`](http://ideone.com/OQ12eM). I tried to provide a simpler solution :). Or an unroll-the-loop version with a lookahead: [`regexp {NOTPLD STATS:([^P]*(?:P(?!ackets:)[^P]*)*)Packets:[\s]+([0-9]+)} $a t1 t2 c`](http://ideone.com/eUyO3l).